# Составление рекурсивного запроса

Tags: sql-server

Пишу рекурсивный запрос и в рекурсивной части надо объединить несколько запросов через `union`. Но SQL ругается на синтаксис.

```
    with GetParentAddr(fm, pid, id, lv, ls, sh, pc)
as (
    select FormalName, ParentGuid, AOGUID, AOLEVEL, LiveStatus, ShortName, PostalCode
    from [ExtFias].[AddressObject] 
    where aoguid ='{3F6AD2A6-CADB-433C-A44A-8E1C637F5515}' and LiveStatus = 1 

    union all

    select FormalName, ParentGuid, AOGUID, AOLEVEL, LiveStatus, ShortName, PostalCode
    from [AddressObject]   
    union 
    select '', AOGUID, HouseGuid, 0,  0, '', PostalCode
    from [HouseObject] t 

    inner join GetParentAddr v on t.AOGUID = v.pid 

    )
    select * from GetParentAddr
go
```

Нужно объединить `AddressObject` и `HouseObject` но ругается на второй `union`. Можно ли таким образом составить запрос ?

Ошибка

`Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Recursive common table expression 'GetParentAddr' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.`

Comment: открытый Union недопустим внутри рекурсивной части, делайте `select .... from (select ... union select ...) X join GetParentAddr ...`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Это помогло